# Centre of mass location

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

How and why is com affected when an EXTERNAL force is is applied ?
What forces do we consider internal ?
Please provide some visual examples
Like men walking on plank, wedge mass system.

Comment: there is no consensus on which forces are internal and which forces are external. It simply depends on what you are interested in. F.e. when you have bunch of galaxies, you want to model galaxy as one system so the gravity between its stars are internal forces of the system. But when you are interested in one particular solar system in given galaxy you might want to model other stars as background and their forces acting on your solar system as external.

Comment: So you mean this concept is all based on convineniance and what is needed to calculate at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Umaxo is correct, forces are neither inherently internal nor external.

One example of a way to consider whether a force is internal or external is to define the system upon which or within which forces are applied.  Once the system has been defined, then external forces are those caused by an external agent outside of the system. Internal forces are then those exerted by one part of the system on another.

When a system is subjected to an external force that does work on the system, there is a change in the amount of energy of the system. When a system is subjected to an internal force where the force exerted by one part of the system does work on another part of the system, there is no change in the amount of energy in the system.

Take the example of a system defined as an object of mass $m$ and the earth. The force that the earth exerts on the object (gravitational force) is then considered an internal force. When gravity does work on the object, such as when the object falls, the  object loses gravitational potential energy but gains an equal amount of kinetic energy. The total change in energy (kinetic + potential) is zero.

Now suppose you, who are not part of the defined object/earth system lifts the object off the floor and places it on a table height $h$ above the floor. You, as the external agent, have done work equal to $mgh$ on the object/earth system increasing its gravitational potential energy. You've increased the energy of the earth/object system.

Now for your questions:

***How and why is com affected when an EXTERNAL force is is applied ?***

If your system is defined as consisting of only the object and it center of mass, then any force exerted on the object and causing a displacement of the object, whether or not the force is applied to the COM, is an external force that does work on the system. If the force is applied to the COM through a distance, the object gains translational kinetic energy. If it is not applied to the COM, the object gains both translational and rotational kinetic energy.

***Please provide some visual examples Like men walking on plank, wedge mass system.***

I gave you the example of an object/earth system. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "men walking on a plank" or a "mass wedge system", but whatever they mean, you can apply the criteria given above if you define what constitutes the system in each case.

Hope this helps.